# facing weird issue in importing android resources in android studio , (required jdk setup as an error correction)

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

everything was just great until sudden PC turnoff during using android studio. so after restart the PC ,and when i tried to load my projects the studio showed an error in importing android resources as

```
android.app.Activity;
android.content.Context;
android.content.Intent;
```

and the error not just for importing ,but also for everything from this classes .even when i started a new project.

and when i tried to fix the error it asked me to setup the jdk ,and when i did nothing is happened .i had tried everything i uninstalled the A-Studio and also i had removed the jdk and the sdk and downloaded the latest vers again but nothing changed.

so any help please  , cause I'm stuck on.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need JAVA JDK 7, latest version of java not full supported in android.

That happening because your system not generating R class. it seems you are using windows. you don't have to install software again. sometimes it can be fix by just re-Building your project or restarting system.

You should also enable Auto-import from settings.

if you still have this issue, make a new profile in Windows and try to use android studio in that new profile. hope this will help you

or you can tell me if still face this error.

Comment: thank you and yes i'm on win 7-64, but before this sudden pc off everything was ok with JDK-8u20 , and i did restart my pc several times. as well re-Building my projects . but now i well try it on efferent profile and i'll tell u what's well happen .

Comment: i did another uninstall\install to jdk and studio ,but with reg cleaning and deleting ( .android , .AndroidStudio , .gradle ) in users folder .and finally this is WORK.

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVE my problem by uninstall \ install the jdk and the android studio ,but with deleting the ( .android , .AndroidStudio , .gradle ) folders in :\Users\name .and you can still use the old SDK .